# Unable to validate one of two signatures that were signed the same way

Tags: solidity, signature, verify, ecrecover, ledger-nano-s

I have a contract that requires two witnesses to sign. Signatures are both being generated using the same code, but I am only able to validate Witness A. Witness B is never found, always just get the zero address for some reason.

JavaScript that generates signatures **(Witness A as example)**:

```
const hash = "0x" + ethereumjsabi
  .soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256", "string", "address"],
    [
      "0xfCab1090e039D4B44c3862F46b7d55bC256AB041",
      10000000,
      "PJUbjAc4oNTkafj6xV2R8kRYDB9MjK2vuu",
      "0x8809465617E09405a1af06C2d93C2bcE0Ce5Ac80",
    ]
  )
  .toString("hex");

const signature = await this.web3.eth.personal.sign(hash, "0x8809465617E09405a1af06C2d93C2bcE0Ce5Ac80");
```

Solidity to validate signatures:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
import "remix_tests.sol"; // this import is automatically injected by Remix.

contract VerificationTest {

    function prefixed(bytes32 hash) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash));
    }

    function checkIt () public {
        bytes memory witnessASignature = hex"8ee674e7c0105a914066d3554ee62a89f07a7a56ad5697695969b3219d8dc9da459d6f290db10b27a374010fb0abc5984dfeb8b380aa8f3564d4361217535e461b";
        bytes memory witnessBSignature = hex"8e474293656af3b93f36169062adeee942d0f2a5450d80110dcb8943863570a96312cdb64030ad3b12203755ac6a597798bede06667e95a7d3d5b3f3bed15b5e01";

        require(witnessASignature.length == 65, "invalid signature A length");
        require(witnessBSignature.length == 65, "invalid signature B length");

        bytes32 _ar;
        bytes32 _as;
        uint8 _av;

        assembly {
            _ar := mload(add(witnessASignature, 32))
            _as := mload(add(witnessASignature, 64))
            _av := byte(0, mload(add(witnessASignature, 96)))
        }

        bytes32 _br;
        bytes32 _bs;
        uint8 _bv;

        assembly {
            _br := mload(add(witnessBSignature, 32))
            _bs := mload(add(witnessBSignature, 64))
            _bv := byte(0, mload(add(witnessBSignature, 96)))
        }

        address witnessAAddress = 0x8809465617E09405a1af06C2d93C2bcE0Ce5Ac80;
        address witnessBAddress = 0x71eb10a6566cCA81Dd2892d36c55359AfedD3CFA;

        uint256 _amount = 10000000;
        string memory _externalAddress = "mi4VcxS4dsw9PzFAeTFJD17v2B7i24eMfQ";

        Assert.equal(ecrecover(prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(0xfCab1090e039D4B44c3862F46b7d55bC256AB041, _amount, _externalAddress, witnessAAddress))), _av, _ar, _as), witnessAAddress, "A not equal!");
        Assert.equal(ecrecover(prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(0xfCab1090e039D4B44c3862F46b7d55bC256AB041, _amount, _externalAddress, witnessBAddress))), _bv, _br, _bs), witnessBAddress, "B not equal!");
    }
}
```

[image: Result from test when run on Remix IDE]

Comment: How did you get the second signature? It has an incorrect `v` value of `01`. Possible values are `1b` or `1c`. Some signing libraries use `00` and `01` for the signature to work you have to replace them by `1b` or `1c`.

Comment: Both signatures are generated using the same method. We both sign via the same UI using MetaMask. We have tested it with a third witness, which worked just fine, but as you said, the other witness signature has a `01` `v` value. If I manually change it to `1c` in my Remix test, then it passes. Idk why it would mess up that value though.

Comment: We figured out what was going on based on your comment @Ismael. Feel free to post an answer, which I will then accept. Otherwise I'll accept my own answer in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, with the comment from Ismael about the incorrect `v` value, the first B witness realised what was going on. **He was using a ledger, which was set to Ethereum mainnet**. Someone we were discussing the problem with then remembered that the `v` value is based on network, so we quickly saw the issue.